# How to use single jpa specification for multiple entities

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I need to write some criteria on different entities and multiple columns. Currently i have multiple specification classes one for ekach entity. How can i make it single jpa specification common for all entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to apply mutliple specifications on different entities to get a result, you won't be able to mix different specification types because specifications are tied to the entities you are trying to retrieve from your query.
However you can achieve such a result by chaining specifications for the entity you are trying to retrive, using joins.

Let's say you have an entity Product, which contains Field entities with a "name" attribute, which themselves contain FieldValue entities with a "value" attributes. You want to retrieve the Product by an Field name having one or more FieldValues. Here is a piece of code which would get you the desired result:

```java
Specification<Product> fieldNameHavingValues(String fieldName, List<String> fieldValues) {
    return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        if (fieldName == null || fieldValues == null || fieldValues.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        Join<Product, Field> fieldJoin = root.join(Product_.fields); // First join on Field table
        Predicate namePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(fieldJoin.get(Field_.name), fieldName); // Assert that the field name has the desired one
        Join<Field, FieldValue> valueJoin = fieldJoin.join(Field_.fieldValues); // Join the third table, i.e. the FieldValue table
        Expression<String> expression = valueJoin.get(FieldValue_.value); 
        Predicate valuePredicate = expression.in(fieldValues); // Assert that the values are in the given collection
        return criteriaBuilder.and(namePredicate, valuePredicate); // Return the combined predicate

    });
}

List<Product> prods = productRepository.findAll(fieldNameHavingValues("colors", Arrays.asList("blue", "orange")));
```

This particular example will retrieve the list of all products having a field named "colors" containing either "blue" or "orange" value.

Note that you will have to make your repository extend JpaSpecificationExecutor :

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product>
```

and to generate metamodels, for example using Maven:

```java
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps